# Physical meaning of sharpness in ios corehaptics

Tags: ios, haptic-feedback

According to the developer documentation, the parameter *hapticsharpness* is not explained very clearly to me because there are only descriptions about haptic feedback, and no physical meaning.

I tried to figure it out from the vibration waveforms I tested in the lab, but it turns out that sharpness will affect both vibration acceleration and frequency. So, it comes to my second question: what is the point of creating another parameter *hapticintensity* if sharpness can already control acceleration? Any idea will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is pretty clear about the fact that [`hapticIntensity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics/chhapticevent/parameterid/3114595-hapticintensity) refers to the amplitude (strength) of the vibration, whereas [`hapticSharpness`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics/chhapticevent/parameterid/3114596-hapticsharpness) controls the nature / feel of it.

Imagine a scenario where you want to simulate a knee-jerk reaction like an error, you might want to use a haptic feedback with a high sharpness, whereas imagine a scenario where you want to convey a soothing haptic feedback like maybe a calm loading indicator (nothing more useful comes to my mind right now ☺️).

You may want to still vary the intensity of these haptic which feedback while still maintaining the same 'feel'. If you had a single API then this would not be feasible.